# Событие над полосой прокрутки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Какое событие возникает, если курсор мыши попал в область полосы прокрутки?

Не движение полосы прокрутки .scroll, а просто попал в любую ее область?

Comment: Таких событий нет... Разве что в css можно это отследить, и то не кроссплатформенно.

Comment: Мне приходит в голову только собственный кастомный скроллер делать дивами вместо нативного

Comment: Вот и мне пришло лишь такое в голову, что свой скроллер писать, и тогда можно на div событие поймать.Проковырял все думал может не нахожу, во и решил спросить.

Comment: @Андрей Солуянов, чем мой ответ не устраивает?

Answer (score 2):

Вам это нужно было? В примере использую событие `mousemove`. Т.е. при малейшем сдвиге курсора по скролл-бару будет срабатывать событие. Вы можете попробовать другие события.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    if(event.target === $('html')[0] && event.clientX >= document.documentElement.offsetWidth)
      console.log('Курсор на скролл-баре');
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Это второй способ с контейнерами. Можно использовать несколько контейнеров. Костыльно, конечно, но физически работает.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".container_for_element").mouseenter(function(event){
            if($(event.target).is($(this))) {     
            console.log('Курсор НА скролл-баре');
            } 
 });
 
 $(".container_for_element").mouseout(function(event){
            if($(event.target).is($(this))) {     
            console.log('Курсор НЕ на скролл-баре');           
            } else {console.log('Курсор НА скролл-баре');}
 });   
 
});
```

```css
.container_for_element {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.element {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container_for_element">
  <div class="element">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container_for_element">
  <div class="element">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вариант ответа хорош!, для прокрутки родной браузеровской, но даже и это все равно скажем костыль.А не событие. Но как отловить на прокрутках которые образованы в блоках div? уже будет другой ибо event.clientX уже там не прокатит.Можит я конечно чет о не учитываю, но кажется так.

Comment: Наверное именно события, такого все же нет. На отловку скрола от браузера ваш вариант рабочий. Но на отловку скрола внутри div уже какая то другая история.Конечно можно по аналогии написать отлов за выходы за границы div, ну это уже целя мега функция, которая учитывает положение div его размеры.И опять костыль.И равносильно что написать свой скрол.

Comment: да, костыль, т.к. системно у скролла нет нужного вам события. А для отловки скролла внутри div можно сделать чуть по другому. Если нужно, могу переделать для дивов.

Comment: Ну напиши если не трудно ,просто с учетом  например что есть некий div $('.menu') и в нем прокрутка может не только мне понадобиться, вообще конечно дич, за все время с развития инета, не реализовали все возможные события штатными средствами.

Comment: Мне просто кроме варианта ,определения положения div ,высчитывания его размеров, и положение курсора со сдвигам за границы div на n пикселей равных полосе прокрутки не приходит. С точки зрения теоретической части.

Comment: добавил второй вариант

Comment: Не совсем этот код корректно работает, так как он отлавливает события над div и выход за его границы. За границы любые, левые правые. Что скрол баром не является.

Comment: по другому пока не знаю как..

Comment: Не ну ты красава !хоть и ответ прям не найден, но в разные стороны сильно покрутил тему, Варианты по любому интересные,спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо) Есть еще одна идейка. Если найду время, то сделаю. А вообще, лучше сделай кастомный скролл, и не мучайся)